# Spliting the generated PDF from jsPDF to a certain div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

I hope everyone is healthy and having a nice vacation.
I am trying to create PDFs from html using using jsPDF.
My framework is ReactJS.
I have something like

```
<Container>
  <div className="div1">...</div>
  <div className="div2">...</div>
  <div className="div3">...</div>
  <div className="div4">...</div>
</Container>
```

the code I am using for the jsPDF is:

```
const generatePDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: "p",
      unit: "pt",
      format: "a4",
      putOnlyUsedFonts: false,
    });
    doc.html(document.querySelector("Container"), {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save(
          `pdfName.pdf`
        );
      },
      margin: [40, 40, 60, 20],
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.8, 
        width: 1000, 
      },
    });
  };
```

Is there a way to split the break the page into Page 1 upd to div with class=2 and Page 2  divs 3 and 4?